# Android Async task slowing down my UI Thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to Android Application development and was having a problem with Async tasks. 
So I'm trying to create an ECG graphing application that does some background processing while the graphing is happening.

I've defined the following Async task -

```
private class Erosion extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...unused ) {

        int i,tempIndex;
        double[] tempArray = new double[13];
        double min = ecgSamples[ecgSampleForErosionIndex] - gArray[0]; 
        while (ecgIncoming)
        {
            if (ecgSampleForErosionIndex > 179999)
            {
                ecgSampleForErosionIndex = 0; 
            }

            for(i= 0;i<13;i++)
            {
                tempIndex = ecgSampleForErosionIndex + i; 
                if (tempIndex > 179999)
                {
                    tempIndex =  (ecgSampleForErosionIndex + i) - 180000;
                }
                tempArray[i] = ecgSamples[tempIndex] - gArray[i];
                if (tempArray[i] < min)
                {
                    min = tempArray[i];
                }

            }

            //min needs to be stored in the erosionFirst Array

            if (erosionFirstArrayIndex > 179999)
            {
                erosionFirstArrayIndex = 0; 
            }


            ecgErosion[erosionFirstArrayIndex] = min; 
            erosionFirstArrayIndex++;
            ecgSampleForErosionIndex++;


        }
        return null;


    }

    } //End of Async Task
```

So all I'm trying to do is modify the content of a particular array in the async task - i dont need to update the UI (at least not for now)

However, when I run this async task my ECG graphing slows down and becomes jerky. When I comment out the "new Erosion().execute();" part in the code where I start the Async task, the graphing becomes normal again.

Isn't an async task supposed to be on a separate thread and so not affecting how things are happening on my UI thread? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if you run a heavy piece of code on a background thread it will still affect the CPU load of the device and therefore might cause delays in your UI thread as well, specially if the device has single-core CPU.

It seems like you have a very heavy loop in you doInBackground method, which runs constantly and just use the CPU nonstop, which overloads it. I'm not sure what this loop is for, but if it doesn't have to refresh constantly you might want to consider adding a thread sleep, allowing other threads to get more CPU time :

```
    while (ecgIncoming)
    {
      ... do your thing ...
      Thread.sleep(100); // wait for 100 milliseconds before running another loop
    }
```

Obviously the "100" is just a number, if the array can update once a second, make it a 1000, etc...

Comment: Yeah, I'm running the async task constantly because I'm using the ECG data to compute the heart rate in real time. It is pretty heavy amount of work going on - so I guess your explanation makes sense. Is there something else other than Async task I can use to perform a constant background computation work?

Comment: @stu90: "Is there something else other than Async task I can use to perform a constant background computation work?" -- nothing that will change your problem. That thread is already set to background priority, but that will not help much with the busy loop you have. Busy loops like this have been considered poor form for a couple of decades. You need to establish a sampling rate and allow other threads a chance at the CPU, as Talihawk suggests. You are also better served forking your own thread, rather than tying up a thread from the `AsyncTask` pool indefinitely.

Comment: @stu90 You could use a Service instead of an Async task, but I doubt that alone will make much of a difference in performance.  You could ssign that Service to run on a separate Linux process, but again I can't say if that will or won't matter.  This should help you get started though: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm going to try doing the background processing in a different way so that the Async task isn't always running in the busy loop.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are you running `new Erosion().execute();` multiple times? That might cause it because you are allocating a new `AsyncTask` multiple times.

Comment: nope just once! but it runs for a really long period in the background.. so i guess that's why it's taking up too much CPU resources.